# jQuery plugin will not show if ASP.Net dropdown value is selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down list in ASP.Net with the options 'No' and 'Yes.' When 'Yes' is selected, I want a jQuery plugin to appear beneath the ddl. I can get the plugin to appear just by calling it, but I have an if-statement that isn't working.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#<% ddlColorChart.Yes %> option:selected')) {
            $('#colorpickerBox').ColorPicker({ flat: true });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am getting the following compiler error message:
Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

I can't find where I'm missing the semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
if ($('#<% ddlColorChart.Yes %> option:selected')) {
```

be

```
if ($('#<%=ddlColorChart.ClientID %> option:selected')) {
```

To summarize you need to render the ID of the control

Hence I've  change .Yes property to use .ClientID

Also you where missing an = <%= which is the equivalent of Response.Write. Because of this that is why you were getting the compile error about the semicolon.

Complete example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#<%=ddlColorChart.ClientID %> option:selected')) {
           if($(this).val() == "Yes"){
              $('#colorpickerBox').ColorPicker({ flat: true });
           }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is 'ClientID'? How do I check to see if the value 'Yes' is selected?

Comment: ClientID is the just that. The ID that's rendered down to the client. To check the value after the if you can use $(this).val(). So something like if($(this).val() == "Yes"){}

Comment: Ooooh, I see. I was trying to connect .val() to the first if-statement.